# IntelliJ Customize Data Views for Debugger: How to have a multiline expression for Java Data Type Renderers?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to customize the way the IntelliJ debugger display the value of `Set` objects. Therefore I created a new `Java Data Type Renderers` in the `Customize Data Views` dialog and pasted this code into the `Use following expression` field:

```
String s = "";
if (this.size() > 0) {
  Iterator iterator = this.iterator();
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    s += iterator.next();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      s += ", ";
      do {
        s += iterator.next();
      } while (iterator.hasNext());
    }
  }
}
return s;
```

However following error is shown in the debugger: `Unable to evaluate the expression Initializer for 's' has incompatible type`.
How should I write a multiline expression into the field so my above code works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use `String.join(", ", this)`
It should look something like this.
[image: Image showing what to change on the customize data views dialog]

If you are using an older version of Java you can use.

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<?> iter = this.iterator();
    if (iter.hasNext())
        sb.append(iter.next().toString());
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(iter.next().toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

IntelliJ highligted the `iterator` code in red but it still works. 
[image: How to the long version should look]

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with using just:

```
this.toString()
```

Comment: Good point. The only difference is the surrounding [] brackets.